# Linq on datatable no datasource exception

Tags: linq, datatable

```
 dataSet = clsDb.MailData("SELECT * FROM CM_Mail cm WHERE cm.[ActualTime] < '" + DateTimeOffset.UtcNow + "' ", CommandType.Text);
        DataTable datatablepending = (from ds in dataSet.Tables[0].AsEnumerable() where ds.Field<string>("Status") == MailStatus.Pending.ToString() select ds).CopyToDataTable();
        DataTable datatableInprogress = (from ds in dataSet.Tables[0].AsEnumerable() where ds.Field<string>("Status") == MailStatus.Inprogress.ToString() select ds).CopyToDataTable();

        if (datatablepending.Rows.Count != 0)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < datatablepending.Rows.Count; i++)
            {

                dataSet = clsDb.MailData("UPDATE CM_Mail SET [Status] = '" + updateStatus + "',LastProccessedTime = '" + DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.ToString() + "' WHERE Id='" + datatablepending.Rows[i]["Id"].ToString() + "'", CommandType.Text);
            }

        }
        if (datatableInprogress.Rows.Count != 0)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < datatableInprogress.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                dataSet = clsDb.MailData("UPDATE CM_Mail SET [Status] = '" + updateStatus + "',SentTime = '" + DateTimeOffset.UtcNow + "',LastProccessedTime = '" + DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.ToString() + "' WHERE Id='" + datatableInprogress.Rows[i]["Id"].ToString() + "'", CommandType.Text);
            }



        }
```

When I try to do this `datatableInprogress` may not have any rows all the time. At run time, I get an exception saying "no datasource". Why? And what should I do to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Just [clone DataTable structure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.clone.aspx) if there is no rows for your condition:

```
var pendingRows = 
  dataSet.Tables[0].AsEnumerable()
         .Where(r => r.Field<string>("Status") == MailStatus.Pending.ToString());

DataTable datatablepending = pendingRows.Any() ? pendingRows.CopyToDataTable() :
                                                 dataSet.Tables[0].Clone();
```

BTW why you need DataTable? You can get ids!

```
var pendingIds = 
     from r in dataSet.Tables[0].AsEnumerable()
     where r.Field<string>("Status") == MailStatus.Pending.ToString()
     select r.Field<int>("Id");
```

Sorry, I don't know why are you assigning dataSet in a loop, but here is code which reproduces yours:

```
string updateStringFormat = 
 "UPDATE CM_Mail SET [Status] = '{0}',LastProccessedTime = '{1}' WHERE Id='{2}'";

foreach(var id in pendingIds)
{
    var commandText = String.Format(updateStringFormat, updateStatus, DateTimeOffset.UtcNow, id);
    dataSet = clsDb.MailData(commandText, CommandType.Text);
}
```